# How to get HTML attribute values after postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html, custom-data-attribute

this is my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    foreach (Mvc3Intranet.Models.Dispatcher item in ViewBag.DispatcherList)
    {
    <div>
        <input type="text" value="@(item.Fullname)" name="txtName@(item.Id)" data-tmp="@(item.Tmp)" /></div>
    }
    <input type="submit" name="test" value="Save" />
}
```

this is the HTML:

```
<form action="/" method="post">    
    <div>
        <input type="text" value="Ray1" name="txtName1" data-tmp="AAA" /></div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" value="Ray2" name="txtName2" data-tmp="BBB" /></div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" value="Ray3" name="txtName3" data-tmp="CCC" /></div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" value="Ray4" name="txtName4" data-tmp="DDD" /></div>
    <input type="submit" name="test" value="Save" />
</form>
```

after form postback, how do i access to `data-tmp` values in the controller?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string test)
{
}
```

`Request["txtName1"]` returns the `valid` of textbox but not the `data-tmp` attribute value. Since this can be done in asp.net web form, i assume the same in asp.net mvc also, or not?

Comment: Any reason why not using the HTML Helper methods to render the form elements ?

Comment: Attributes are not included as part of the POSTed Request[] variables.

Comment: @Shyju, i like to keep as much html as possible in the view since it's closer to assembly the final output.

Comment: @RayCheng couldn't agree more to the way you think. About the question, that's a nice one. I'll do a little search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes aren't included in the Request.Forms dictionary. You would have to post your additional data as a hidden field or to the query string

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could store your data-temp in an Array or Dictionary and save it in a session-var.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("txtName1", "AAA");
dict.Add("txtName2", "BBB");
//or put the above lines in your foreach loop
this.Session["data-tmp"] = dict;
```

...and then use the following line to retrieve the Dictionary from the session var:

```
Dictionary<string, string> recoverDict = (Dictionary<string, string>)this.Session["data-tmp"];
```